# Measure returning same value for all columns in Matrix visual

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create two columns for each product, one that reflects current year sales and another that shows prior year sales.

My underlying data already aggregates all sales by year. In this example I have three tables. One that contains the main sales. And the other is just a measure table where I store all my measures related to sales in Denver. So `Denver Sales[Sales]` is essentially just a measure which filters the `'Main Sales'` table for Denver data only. This measure if defined as follows:

```
Sales = CALCULATE(SUM('Main Sales'[Sales]),
                  FILTER('Main Sales', 'Main Sales[City] = "Denver")
                 )
```

The third table is the `Product` table, which only contain two columns Product Name and Product ID. It has a relationship with `Main Sales` based on the Product ID.

So in order to get the PY sales, I tried to create a measure with the following DAX code:

```
PY Sales =
VAR py_sales =
    CALCULATE(
       'Denver Sales'[Sales],
       FILTER ( ALLSELECTED('Main Sales'), 'Main Sales'[Year] = MAX ( 'Main Sales'[Year]) -1 )
   )
RETURN
  py_sales
```

However, as you can see below. The PY Sales column is taking the sum of all 3 products' PY sales for each year, rather than just the individual product.

[image]

Can anyone help me understand why my code is doing this?

Comment: It would help if you adhered to a more consistent naming convention with respect to columns and measures. The measure [Sales], for example, includes the table name 'Denver Sales', whereas the column [Year] omits any table reference. Best practice is considered to be the contrary, i.e. include table names when referencing columns and exclude them when referencing measures. Also, my eye is drawn to the fact that your measure references two tables, Denver Sales and Main Sales, though we do not know the relationship between these tables. Nor have you shared the definition for the measure [Sales].

Comment: Can you provide sample data from your tables? So we can have an idea about the data structure?

Comment: @JosWoolley thanks for your reply. I added some additional info to my questions based on your suggestion. Essentially, Main Sales is a table which contains the original data. And Denver Sales is merely a measure table that house all my measures related to Denver. So Denver Sales[Sales] is a measure which calculates sales from the main table but with a filter for Denver only.  The Product information is coming from a third table, which has a relationship with the 'Main Sales' table based on a product ID.

Comment: Thanks. Re "*Denver Sales[Sales] is a measure which calculates sales from the main table but with a filter for Denver only*", it might still be useful to see your definition for that measure.

Comment: Sure. So the measure is defined as per the following: Sales = CALCULATE(SUM('Main Sales'[Sales]),FILTER('Main Sales', 'Main Sales[City] = "Denver")). You can see in this formula that there is a column called 'City' which I use to filter for Denver only before summing the sales column.